# Auto-generate documentation templates for Swift code in XCode 7.2

Tags: xcode, swift, documentation-generation

Is it possible to auto-generate a documentation template for a given method in XCode?

Example of a documentation template:

```
///  
/// - parameter x: 
/// - parameter y: 
/// - parameter w: 
/// - parameter d: 
/// - returns: T
```

Corresponding to this method:

```
func subface(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, w: CGFloat, d: Int) -> UIImage{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you can use appleDoc, just search for appleDoc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add **[VVDocumenter-Xcode](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode)** via [**Alcatraz** Package Manager](http://alcatraz.io/).

> this is an example after writing **`///`** above the function definition.

```
     /**
     <#Description#>

     - parameter x: <#x description#>
     - parameter y: <#y description#>
     - parameter w: <#w description#>
     - parameter d: <#d description#>

     - returns: <#return value description#>
     */
    func subface(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, w: CGFloat, d: Int) -> UIImage{
       /*...*/
    }
```

> The **`<# .. >`** marked sections are editable with just tapping over them.

Comment: I installed the  Alcatraz and  VVDocumenter-Xcode, but how do I activate it ?

Comment: did you installed **VVDocumenter** via **Package Manager** submenu in **Window** menu in Xcode?

Comment: Normally you need to restart Xcode. After adding a new package, an alert should popup saying something like "Load Bundle/Skip Bundle". Just click on load bundle and you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is shortcut: command + option + /

Comment: Sure, but not in Xcode 7.2, which is the version used by OP. This shortcut was introduced in Xcode 8. At the time of the question and answer it was not available.